# Invoking class for test question

Tags: apex, unit-test

The syntax of invoking the class in a test eludes me still (not so on triggers!).

If my class is the simple:

```
public class MyOppsApprovalExt {

    public MyOppsApprovalExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


   public List <Opportunity> getOppsInApproval (){ 
       return [select Name,  Business_Line__c, Accountid, State__c, Approval_Status__c  from Opportunity where ownerID =:userinfo.getuserId() and Approval_Status__c != 'New Accounts Final Approval'and Approval_Status__c != ''];
    }



}
```

I understand to insert a user, Account, opportunity etc. but then how to invoke the class? 
Do I need to process a  list through the method, or a user? Please assist, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax to instantiate a class, in your example is like this:

```
MyOppsApprovalExt myClass = new MyOppsApprovalExt();
```

Whenever a class is created, a constructor is called. If you don't provide a constructor, like I did in the snippet of code above a default,empty constructor will be called.

In your example, which I believe this is where you have the problem, your constructor needs a parameter. So any time you create a class you need to provide an instance of the Standard controller. In the test you need to do something like this:

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(yourTestRecordHere); // i.e contact, account etc
MyOppsApprovalExt myClass = new MyOppsApprovalExt(sc);

//Call the method of the newly created class
List<Opportunity> opps = myClass.getOppsInApproval();
```

Have a read about [Using Constructors](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_constructors.htm)

And now that you know the use of a constructor, I will throw in the question ... Do you need the constructor for this class?

Are those methods only helper methods? If so you can declare them static and not even worry about instantiating the class you could just call them

```
public static List<ProcessInstanceStep> getSteps() {
      return [select id, StepStatus from ProcessInstanceStep where Stepstatus != 'Approved'];
}
List<Opportunity> opps = MyOppsApprovalExt.getOppsInApproval();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this compiled when I removed the word Set from ApexPages.standardSetController(yourTestRecordHere) - I am still learning, thanks

Comment: I removed the process step query from my sample as I can discard it.  I am not sure how to 'invoke' the query to cover it. It is not covered now.

Comment: Sorry I meant StandardController and not StandardSetController... Don't know why I typed Set, edited my answer. To answer your second question you just have to call the method in your test, make sure you have the correct test data created first. The query should be covered if you call the method.

Comment: Hmm, "the query should be covered if I call the method" -isn't this calling the method or do I misunderstand?:  ApexPages.StandardController sc = new  ApexPages.StandardController(myTestOpportunity);
        MyOppsApprovalExt myClass = new MyOppsApprovalExt(sc);

Comment: You still need to call it like this   myClass.getOppsInApproval(). Will edit my answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can call your class directly from the test method.  It will run in the context of whoever is running the test.

```
@isTest
private class MyOppsApprovalExtTest {

    static testmethod void test_MyOppsApprovalExt() {

        MyOppsApprovalExt ext = new MyOppsApprovalExt();

        List<Opportunity> opptys = ext.getOppsInApproval();
        List<ProcessInstanceStep> steps = ext.getSteps();

        //assertions, etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: iT SAYS Constructor not defined:  I am not clear on this error