# Trying to make Apex Test Class for VF page extension class but keep getting errors

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller-extension, failing-tests

Trying to save this Apex Test Class keep getting error

> Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined:   [GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller].() at line 35 column 51

Here is the VF page extension:

```
public with sharing class GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller {
    public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList {get; set;}
    public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 {get; set;}
    public Decimal lon1 { get; set; }
    public Decimal lat1 { get; set; }

    public GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        MeetingsList2 = [SELECT Name, Group__c, Business_Value__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__c = :id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c ASC LIMIT 1];
        MeetingsList = [SELECT Name, Group__c, Business_Value__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__c = :id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1];

        if (MeetingsList2.size() > 0 ) {
            lat1 = MeetingsList2[0].GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s;
            lon1 = MeetingsList2[0].GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s;
        } else {
            lat1 = -0.023559;
            lon1 = 37.90619300000003;
        }
    }
} // end class
```

Here is the Extension class test class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller_Tester {
    static testMethod void TestcustomGroupLookup () {

        Location__c objLocation = new Location__c();
        objLocation.name = 'testlocation';
        insert objLocation;
        System.debug('::::objLocation.Id:::: ' + objLocation.Id);
        System.debug('::::objLocation.name:::: ' + objLocation.name);

        Group__c objGroup = new Group__c();
        objGroup.name = 'testgroup';
        objGroup.Location__c = objLocation.Id;
        insert objGroup;
        System.debug('::::objGroup.Id:::: ' + objGroup.Id);
        System.debug('::::objGroup.name:::: ' + objGroup.name);

        Meeting__c objMeeting = new Meeting__c();
        objMeeting.Group__c = objGroup.id;
        objMeeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s = -0.39348930;
        objMeeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s = 37.00245300;
        objMeeting.Meeting_Date__c = date.today();
        objMeeting.Credit_Repaid__c = 100;
        objMeeting.Credit_Sales__c = 1000;
        objMeeting.Cash_In_Hand__c = 10;
        objMeeting.Stock_Value__c = 100;
        objMeeting.Assets_Bought__c = 100;
        objMeeting.Cash_Sales__c = 100;
        insert objMeeting;
        System.debug('::::objMeeting.Id::::' + objMeeting.Id);
        System.debug('::::objMeeting.Group__c::::' + objMeeting.Group__c);

        PageReference myVfPage = Page.BomaGroupWithMap;
        Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objGroup.id);
        System.debug('::::id::::' + id);

        //construct controller
        GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller controller = new GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller();

        List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList = new List<Meeting__c>();
        List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 = new List<Meeting__c>();

        MeetingsList = [SELECT Name, Group__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__c = :id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1 ];
        MeetingsList2 = [SELECT Name, Group__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__c = :id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1 ];
    }
}
```

Any help? Please. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just answered a similar question, have a look http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/invoking-class-for-test-question/66635#66635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you tried to instantiate the class with controller which was not defined:

in `GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller` defined constructor with parameter

```
public GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```

thus you have to use constructor with argument in test class.
For example if your tested page processes an Account record:

```
Account record = new Account(name='Test');
ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.standardController(record);
GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller controller    = new GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller(stdController);
```

Comment: Hey @Pavel , Thanks for the response. Tried to put an argument such but still got an error, do you mind using an example?

Comment: @Kollo please see update in the answer

Comment: Thank You! That solved the problem now on  to testing. Thank you again Pavel